# Definite Integral of $\int_{0}^{\infty}3^{-4(z^2)}dz$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Please help me  insolving this
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}3^{-4(z^2)}dz$$

I tried to do normal substitution but it didn'd work.... I wonder it is complex integration... I dont need the solution rather just need the approach to go to solution..Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: i tried to do normal substitution but it didn'd work.... I wonder it is complex integration... I dont need the solution rather just need the approach to go to solution..Thanks in advance

Comment: The approach is to rewrite the inner expression into the form $e^{az^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaussian Integral (for $a\gt0$) is given as
$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-az^2}dz=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$

$$3^{-4z^2}=e^{-4\ln 3z^2 }\implies a=4\ln3$$

> $$\large\int_{0}^{\infty}3^{-4z^2}dz=\frac14\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\ln 3}}$$

Comment: Perfect...Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Rewrite $$3^{-4z^2}=e^{-4z^2 \log(3)}$$ and make an appropriate change of variable to arrive to something looking like $e^{-x^2}$

Comment: Maybe you should use $\ln$ for the neutral logarithm and not the general form $\log_n$

Comment: Yes I could, but I only know one logarithm (joke !) !